# how to display image by last created in database in jsp

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp

This is my code. I have image in folder and file path in database i want retrieve all image by last created row I mean I want to show first last image.

```
<%@ include file="getcon.jsp"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>View Image Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0">
<!-- main content -->
<%
String type=request.getParameter("type");
String sql;

if(type!=null)
       {
    sql="SELECT PICTURE, TITLE, TAG, POST from testimage where type='"+type+"'";




ResultSet rs=null;
try
{

rs=st.executeQuery(sql);


while(rs.next())
{
%>
<table width="700%" height="600" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<!-- Mention Directory where your images has been saved-->
 <% String filename=rs.getString(2);

                                  //System.out.println("filename isssssss"+filename);
                                  out.println("<b>"+filename+"</b>");
                                  out.println(application.getRealPath("/"));
                                  //session.setAttribute("download",filename);
                          %>

<td><img src="jokeimage\<%=rs.getString(1)%>" width="500" height="400" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<%
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
out.print(""+e.getMessage());
}
}
else{}
%>
```

Comment: Please try to avoid *Scriplet* instead use JSTL & EL.

Comment: Where is the exactly issue? In accessing database or image from the server, please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and bind parameters (because the current query is susceptible to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)), assuming the `POST` column value increases for each successive row; it's possible to do something like this in a [controller `Servlet`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2) -

```
sql="SELECT PICTURE, TITLE, TAG, POST from testimage where type=? ORDER BY POST DESC";
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  ps.setString(1, type);
  rs = ps.executeQuery();
  // ... Read the ResultSet ...
} finally {
  try {
    rs.close();
  } catch (Exception ignored) {
  }
  try {
    ps.close();
  } catch (Exception ignored) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to avoid *Scriplet elements* instead use [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) that is more easy to use and *less error prone*.

You can use [SQL Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html) that is designed for accessing database in JSP.

Sample code: (*change database URL and credentials*)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<sql:setDataSource var="dataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" user="root" password="" />

<sql:query dataSource="${dataSource}" sql="SELECT PICTURE, TITLE from testimage where type=? ORDER BY CREATION_DATE DESC" var="result">
    <sql:param value="${param.type}"/>
</sql:query>

<table width="100%" height="600" border="1" align="center">
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td><b>${row.tag}</b></td>
            <td><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jokeimage/${row.picture}" width="500" height="400" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

---

How did I converted it into JSTL & EL from Scriplet?

1. `${param.type}` is used for `request.getParameter("type")`
2. `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` is used for `application.getRealPath("/")`
3. `c:forEach` tag is used for `while` loop
4. `sql:param` is used for parametrized query
5. `sql:setDataSource` is used for creating data source
6. `sql:query` is used for executing a query